# Xcode scaling and framing images

Tags: ios, xcode7, scaling

I'm having an issue with framing my background image throughout iOS devices (all iPhones and iPads) I'm trying to maintain certain elements of the UI (which contain buttons) in the screen for an app built in Xcode 7. I'm using a square image as background but Xcode isn't giving me the choice of which area appears. Should I create a new storyboard for each device?[iPhoneframing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P46M.png)[iPhoneframingscaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZYo0.png)

Comment: The question is very vague.  What are you using to present the background image?  What constraints have you set?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Droppy. I'm using a png image and used the auto-layout presets for it. The labels are set at 404 from the left and 118/155 from the bottom.

Comment: Using constraints with absolute point values cannot be best practice.  I think you want to be using some percentage of the containing element, perhaps with an offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create storyboard for each device and you have to put condition for different device in `AppDelegate` file `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {}` method.
But it is not proper way to resolve this type of issue.
For that you have to add constraints.
By using constraints your view appear every device compatible.